# How to filter in one-to-many relationship tables in LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have EVENTS and CATEGORY table. One event may have more than one Category associated. So it is one to many.

When I try to filter CATEGORY table I am getting error
ArgumentException: The property expression `i => i.Category.CategoryName.Contains("Social")` is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: `t => t.MyProperty`. For more information on including related data, see [Loading Related Data](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393) .

Here is my code

```
   var viewModel = new EventIndexData();
            viewModel.Events = await _context.Events
                                 .Include(i => i.Categories)
                                    .ThenInclude(i => i.Category.CategoryName.Contains("Social"))
                                    .AsNoTracking()
                                 .ToListAsync();
```

any help appreciated !

Comment: You have no provided details about your pocos and dbcontext, but anyway please check my answer and let me know if is useful

Comment: Filtered include are not supported yet. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1833

Answer (score 0):

You need first to create a query and append condition:

```
var categoryName = "Social";

var query = _context.Events.Include(i => i.Category);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName))
{
    query = query.Where(item => item.Category.CategoryName.Contains(categoryName));
}

var viewModel = new EventIndexData();

viewModel.Events = await query.ToListAsync();
```

I'm not sure about your objects name, but you can fix in your code.